# Fast Loopback on Windows 10 with weird HyperThreading results

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, winsock, hyperthreading

I have successfully enabled SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH option on Windows 10 even though there isn't much information on whether Windows 10 supports it. Here is some info on the feature [link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj841212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  [link2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx)

I have a basic TCP server and client using send()/recv() API that can be configured to use as many threads as I want.

Now here are the test results, I get the same ratios no matter how many threads I use for the test but to be clear I used 8 sending and 8 receiving threads for results below. Ran on an I7-4770K, with all tests consuming 100% CPU as reported by task manager.

HyperThreading Off (4 logical cores)

SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH enabled : 140K packets per second

SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH disabled: 210K packets per second

HyperThreading On (8 logical cores)

SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH enabled : 140K packets per second

SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH disabled: 80K packets per second

Why is this test with HyperThreading enabled slower than without it? And why does this test perform *SLOWER* when HyperThreading is disabled and the option is enabled. I am quite puzzled by the results as the option improves speed with HT on but not when HT is off, also puzzled by hyperthreading completely tanking the results.